# Stack Exchange Format for Corporate Networks

Tags: discussion, licensing, intellectual-property

I think the Stack Exchange format is great and would like to suggest to my employer that they implement an internal SE for collaboration on our processes. Obviously the network would need to be private to just our company due to proprietary and confidential information.

Does SE license their format that we could purchase a corporate license for?
If the answer is no, then the follow up question; is SE format protected by intellectual property rights that would prevent us from implementing our own similar system?